# Piping the results of an invoke-restmethod in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write some powershell scripts for managing calls to an api, if I store the results in a variable I can iterate over them nicely, but I'd like to get an understanding of how to do it via piping.

This works

```bsh
#This uri returns an array of objects that describe searches via the api
$reports = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $(root)/search -Method get -UseDefaultCredentials
foreach($r in $reports){
    #can do stuff here
}
```

And if I do this I get the results displayed in the console window

```
  $reports = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $(root)/search -Method get -UseDefaultCredentials | select
```

But I can't find a way of using the contents of the results after the pipe

```
#nothing displayed in the console for this
$reports = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $(root)/search -Method get -UseDefaultCredentials | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Id }
```

What is the correct way of accesing the items in the piped results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it right, just pipe it to the [Foreach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $(root)/search -Method get -UseDefaultCredentials | ForEach-Object { 
    # $_ equals $r in your first example
}
```

If you assign the result to a variable, you will get the pipeline result of the `Foreach-Object`.

Comment: My god I'm such a newbie to miss that!

Comment: Also, a quirk to be aware of: sometimes an array is returned, but the whole array gets passed down the pipe (rather than individual items). Putting the `Invoke-RestMethod` call in parenthesis fixes this behavior. [More info here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11201622-invoke-restmethod-returns-an-unrolled-array).